# Launchd won't execute a bindfs command

Tags: macos, filesystem, launchd

I want to use launchd to run bindfs commands at login, as root. I have a plist in /Library/LaunchAgents/loginsftpjailmount.plist (with chmod 600) and a shell script in /usr/local/bin/loginsftpjailmount.sh.

I should start by saying it works - if I change the bash script to run

```
mkdir /Users/Me/Desktop/itworks
```

then it successfully creates the directory "itworks", both on login and by running

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/launchAgents/loginsftpjailmount.plist
```

And the folder created is owned by root and I have to type in my password to delete it. When I manually run the bash script from the terminal using sudo, the bindfs command works.

So to summarize - I know the script works. I know the plist works. I know they work together with launchd. But the bindfs command doesn't run! I checked the system log with

```
sudo grep com.user /var/log/system.log
```

and it says it exits with error 127 (com.user is part of the label for my plist). I searched online and none of the solutions for error 127 work for me. For reference, two plists I have used are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.loginitem</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>bash -c "bindfs /Volumes/BRIGHTRED/ServedDocuments /sftpjail/Documents"</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

and also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.user.loginitem</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/loginsftpjailmount.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I found my own answer. The problem is that bindfs is installed under /opt/local/bin and launchd cannot find it. So by simply changing my shell script to execute the full path, it runs. My shell script is now like "/opt/local/bin/bindfs directory1 directory2" instead of simply "bindfs directory1 directory2" But I have a new problem - it runs when I do sudo load manually, but doesn't run on login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindfs process has to be started with root privileges. Launching it as agent would prevent this.

So `sudo launchctl unload ...` and `sudo launchctl remove ...` (the subcommand *remove* removes the agent from the launchd database - the file won't get deleted!) the plist, move the plist to /Library/LaunchDaemons/ and reload it with `sudo launchctl load ...`.

A properly named and composed org.user.bindfs.sftpjail.plist would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.user.bindfs.sftpjail</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/opt/local/bin/bindfs</string>
                <string>/Volumes/BRIGHTRED/ServedDocuments</string>
                <string>/sftpjail/Documents</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/org.user.bindfs.sftpjail.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/org.user.bindfs.sftpjail.out</string>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Volumes/BRIGHTRED</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The WatchPath key is often required (it was in my case) to avoid timing problems. You may remove the keys StandardErrorPath/StandardOutPath and its strings after ensuring that everything works properly.